# Could we offer a gentle inbox reminder that self-evaluations are happening?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, site-evaluation

Notifications of elections on sites on which we are members are broadcast via the inbox.  I think adding a gentle reminder of a self-evaluation in the inbox would be a worthwhile pursuit.

Elections are crucial to a site's success, but for sites in Beta, a high volume of participation in a self-evaluation is just as critical to get a good sample of users.  Yes, one could argue that those most active on a site would see the notice of the impending evaluation in the Community Bulletin sidebar, but on sites in which the content of the sidebar doesn't change very often, it's unfortunately easy to tune out.  Active users do take time away from their favorite sites as well, and staying away from a site for a week should not grant a *de facto* disqualification from participating in these important evaluations.

I realize that keeping "noise" out of the inbox is a priority, and I don't want it to start reminding me of other users' birthdays or something, but I think this is a case where the injection of information would be warranted.

Comment: Since [community self-evaluations stopped being a thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261601/335251) about a year after this request was made, I'm closing this as "no longer reproducible".