# Admin > Site Self-Eval Stats claims that there will be more site self-evals in the future

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, site-evaluation

The Admin > Site Self-Eval Stats screen (/admin/review/site-eval-stats - diamond-only) claims that a new site self-eval will be spawned six months after the previous one ended. For example, on Anime.SE:

[image]

[But these are no longer a thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261601/), so the text about "Next eval begins..." should probably be removed.

Not a big deal, but I figured it was worth noting.